# Get username and domain using Golang

Tags: windows, go

is there any way to get Windows User name using golang?
I would like to get a Domain too. In my case Domain is "WORKGROUP"

cmd -> systeminfo:

[image]

Comment: [user.Current](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/#Current)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must us os and os/user packages to handle domain and current username

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/user"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(user.Current()) //return current username
    fmt.Println(os.Hostname()) //return the hostname(domain)
}
```

Comment: So `os.Hostname()` returns only the Hostname, not the domain name.

You can get the Domain name by running the `systeminfo` binary on Windows Powershell or CMD. This command will show both the Hostname and the Domain on different lines, `os.Hostname()` is the Hostname, not the domain.

Just a warning for anyone thinking about using this `systeminfo` binary to get the domain name programmatically: Its output gets translated depending on the version of Windows, which is why I am looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

user.Current() returns the user currently running the application. It does NOT return the currently logged in user for which you will need to use the WTS functions of the windows package of golang ("golang.org/x/sys/windows") and retrieve session details of the currently active session.