# How to get Windows display name in Go?

Tags: windows, go

I'm trying to get my Windows username and display name in Go.  I tried `user.Current().Name` but that returns the display name, not the actual username returned by `whoami` in a command prompt.

Comment: Try UserName instead of Name

Comment: What, specifically, is your problem? Maybe include your full code with the output? Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840740/get-username-and-domain-using-golang) should answer your question. See also [this blog post](https://golangcode.com/get-the-current-username-name-and-home-dir-cross-platform/). Those examples work fine for me on my Windows machine. Again, what problem are you running in to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get username and domain using Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840740/get-username-and-domain-using-golang)

Comment: @BurakSerdar that did it, somehow I didn't even see `Username`. I resorted to querying `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\LastLoggedOnDisplayName`, which worked, but this is way cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, `Name` *is* the display name, while `Username` is the actual username (in `domain\username` format).